# DynamicLink receiving nil does not contain valid required param

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

My issue is only on iOS, Android is having no problem receiving the dynamic link

Dynamiclink is nil and when it isn't query params are not there

**Firebase Setup**
short link: https://examplebase.page.link/migration
dynamic link: https://www.examplelink.com/migrate
I've followed every video in firebase dynamic links documentation

**long link I'm trying to use**

> https://examplebase.page.link/?link=https://www.examplelink.com/migrate?migrationToken=123&docNumber=123&apn=py.com.exam.hoc.debug&isi=11223344&ibi=py.com.exam.development

Before using the dynamic link I encode the **deep link** to look like this

> https://examplebase.page.link/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Eexamplelink%2Ecom%2Fmigrate%3FmigrationToken%3D123%26docNumber%3D123&apn=py.com.exam.hoc.debug&isi=11223344&ibi=py.com.exam.development

**Where I process the dynamic link**

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                     restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { dynamiclink, error in
            if let migrationToken = dynamiclink?.url?.valueOf("migrationToken"),
               let documentNumber = dynamiclink?.url?.valueOf("docNumber") {
                if !migrationToken.isEmpty && !documentNumber.isEmpty {
                    //do stuff
                } else {
                    // error
                }
            } else {
                // error
            }
        }    
        return handled
    }
```

> Something to point out my short link has the path variable **/migration** I'm currently not using that in my long link, but if I do, the dynamic link works differently

**Case 1** Using base link without the path variable

Inside this method `DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { dynamiclink, error in }`
dynamiclink is nil even though **userActivity.webpageURL!** has the value of the link received. Error received

> Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: {
> apn = "py.com.exam.hoc.debug";
> efr = 1;
> ibi = "py.com.exam.development";
> isi = 1505794177;
> link = "https://www.examplelink.com/migrate?migrationToken=95e7f2f9-178f-4533-8907-50b656757695&docNumber=4233512";
> }

**Case 2** Using base link with path variable
Inside this method `DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { dynamiclink, error in }`
dynamiclink has the value of `https://www.examplelink.com/migrate` without the query param
In console I see same error than in Case 1

Following one tutorial from Firecast the guy says to set the dynamic link on firebase with the query params set, then my Firebase setup would look like this
**Firebase Setup**
dynamic link: https://www.examplelink.com/migrate?migrationToken=123&docNumber=123

The issue here is that the app receives those params hard coded, they are never replaced